# 404 error on localhost

Tags: php, localhost

I am trying to use some ajax to send some email.  I have done this before using cold fusion and had no issue.

What I am running into is that **localhost** is not finding a file that is clearly in the directory.  In fact the file sits in the same directory as index.php which is finds no problem.  However it gives me a **404 error file not found** on my send.php file.  I have even tried to go directly to the page via the address bar and it does not find the file.  *If I put in the file path ie - file:///C://xampp/htdocs/3H-Web-Wlements/send.php it will display the code.*

However when I upload to my active server it has no issues.

What am I missing here?

Here is the error from the log:
[Wed Sep 23 19:33:34.295785 2015] [:error] [pid 2552:tid 1752] [client ::1:63670] script 'C:/xampp/htdocs/index.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: http://localhost/3H-Web-Wlements/

Do I have something mis-configured or even not configured?
Like I said.  It works on my active server but fails on localhost only.

my send.php code

```
<?php
/*
 **************************************
 *                                    *
 * Config here                        *
 *                                    *
 **************************************
 */

$to = 'xxx@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Message from website';
$siteName = "xxx";

/*
 *************************************************************
 *                                                           *
 *      Don't Change below code, if you don't know php.      *
 *                                                           *
 *************************************************************
 */

$name = $_POST['contactName'];
$mail = $_POST['contactEmail'];
$subject = $_POST['contactWebsite'];
$note = $_POST['contactMessage'];
$ipAdd = $_POST['contactIp'];

if (isset($name) && isset($mail) && isset($note)) {


    // $mailSub = '[Contact] [' . $siteName . '] '.$subject;

    $body = 'Sender Name: ' . $name . "\n\n";
    $body .= 'Sender IP: ' . $ipAdd . "\n\n";
    $body .= 'Sender Mail: ' . $mail . "\n\n";
    $body .= 'Website: ' . $subject . "\n\n";
    $body .= 'Message: ' . $note;

    $message = $body;

    $header = 'From: ' . $mail . "\r\n";
    $header .= 'Reply-To:  ' . $mail . "\r\n";
    $header .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    // mail($to, $mailSub, $body, $header);
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}else{
    echo '0';
}
?>
```

Comment: When you visit file:/// you are opening the file like any other on your browser's file viewer instead of it running on a HTTP web server through http://

Comment: after you get the 404 error, check your Apache (or other webserver...) error log - it will tell you what file Apache _tried_ to serve. That should give you some hints - update us with that file if you can't still figure it out from there. On Ubuntu Linux, I found my error log at `/var/log/apache2/error.log`.

Comment: Yikes. I doesn't appear to redirect - I would expect a blank white screen when called on successfully (or 0 on failure). One last question: on the active server, is the url `example.com/send.php` or `example.com/3H-Web-Wlements/send.php`?

Comment: example.com.  The 3h-web-wlements is just a folder within htdocs.  I structure that way just to keep it clean for examples.  I upload the file contents to the root of the domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error message you provided and the obscurity of the URL you are navigating to on localhost, I suspect the root cause of your issue stems from having two different document roots set up on your development server and production server.

If I'm right, this can be fixed by changing your development server's document root from `C://xampp/htdocs/` to `C://xampp/htdocs/3H-Web-Wlements/`. With this set, the server will attempt to serve `index.php` from `3H-Web-Wlements/` instead of from `htdocs/`.

The document root setting can be set within Apache's configuration file typically called `httpd.conf`. If you're using a development setup like XAMPP or MAMP, you likely have a button in the control panel to get to httpd.conf.

The setting should look like this after the change:

```
DocumentRoot C://xampp/htdocs/3H-Web-Wlements/
```

After making the change, you will need to restart your web server for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Sending email functions on php is much better to test on active server than localhost because localhost needs to configure to support email functions while active server is already set up for this. I also experienced it.

Comment: i can see your point and I am trying to avoid have to do all testing and developing for this live.   I am trying to do is test prior to going active.  I really do not want to have to write additional code just so I can test prior to make live.

Comment: @MarkHart If you verify that your code is working on active server, you can leave that ok and continue coding on other functions that works on localhost. In my case, I create, analyze, do some research for right syntax of code before I test it on active server to lessen the trial and error to active server