# Getting 404 Error while running PHP Script locally using xampp server

Tags: php, apache, xampp

i am new to PHP and started with installing xampp server and writing a php script. Everything looks good but when i click submit on the html form   i am getting error (my apache and php admin both are running)
"The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

> Error 404 localhost Apache/2.4.29 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2n PHP/5.6.33

Currently i am using windows 10 and placed my file ''test1' in htdocs folder in C://xampp. Below is my php code:

```
<?php

if(isset($POST["Submit"])){
$ETask=$POST["ETask"];
$Status=$POST["Status"];
$Connection=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root');
$selected=mysqli_select_db('test',$Connection);
$Query="INSERT INTO test1(task,status) VALUES($ETask,$EStatus)";
$Execute=mysqli_query($Query);
if($Execute){
    echo '<span class="success"> Records have been added successfully </span>';

}
else{
    echo '<span>Please check db connection or error on the page </span>';
}   
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
  <head>
     <title>Insert Into Database</title> 
  </head>
  <body>
<div>
     <form action="test1.php method="POST">
     <fieldset>
Task : <br><input type="task" Name="ETask" value=""><br>
Status : <br><textarea  Name="EStatus" ></textarea><br>
<br><br><input type="Submit" Name="Submit" value="Submit Your Status"><br>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
</html>
```

I have gone through several post but couldn't find solution. Comments & Suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: you missed a double quote, it should be `<form action="test1.php" method="POST">`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32751344/404-error-on-localhost

Answer (score 2):

You missed `"` quote in your form tag.

```
<form action="test1.php" method="POST">
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed to apply double quotes " closing in your form in html.`<form action="test1.php" method="POST">`

Answer (score -1):

Please change from:

```
<form action="test1.php method="POST">
```

To

```
<form action="test1.php" method="POST">
```