# Unable to connect to WebAPI locally from specific Project but fine in other environment or other solution

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-404

Unable to connect to WebAPI locally from specific Project but fine in other environment

I am having an issue connecting to a WebApi project locally. Let's call it project X
When running in browser or POSTMAN I get a 404 Not Found error.

To try to resolve this I have:

- Created a separate bare skeleton Project/Solution(call it project O)
  that I am able to successfully call locally from both browser &
  Postman
- Tested Project X in Release environment, it works there
- But when I test Project X locally, I get the 404 error.
- I also tried looking at an xml log file but can't determine that anything is worthwhile in it (+16,000 lines long)
- Made sure the app.config and web.config were properly updated
- I have looked at other SO articles
  such as :
  [404 error on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32751344/404-error-on-localhost)

The only other thing I've noticed is that when it has https it gives a "Could not get any response error" but when I change to http I get the "404 Not Found" error. But still not sure why it's not finding the resource. I don't believe there is anything wrong with the routing since Project X works in release environment.

Been going at this a few days. What could be the difference between dev/local and release to cause it to give an error in one and not the other?

Comment: I suggest you could firstly check the web.config file to see what the difference between project o and project X. If you still couldn't find out anything, I suggest you could try to enable the [fail request tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis) to see what exactly path for the request.

Comment: How you are testing the application. Are you looking for a resource directly? otherwise trying to authenticate?

Comment: @shyambabu this is the New User Registration page.. so it checks the API/DB if the individual exists and then allows them to create a user.

Comment: @BrandoZhang can fail request tracing still be done for iisexpress? project o has a very simple webconfig since its a skeleton project, whereas project x is a full fledged application. I was not able to determine any differences in areas of the webconfig that had the same tags.

Comment: in the tracelogfile I have <failedRequest url="http://localhost:8080/en/"

Comment: Can you check that AllowInsecureHttp is commented for OAuthOptions in startup.Auth file?